# Null reference on static class property

Tags: c#, static, nullreferenceexception

I have a static class:

```
public static class Options
{
    public static MiscSettings MiscSettings;
    public static Units Units;
}
```

My definitions for the two property classes looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Units
{
    public LengthUnit LengthUnit { get; set; } = LengthUnit.Millimeter;
    public VolumeUnit VolumeUnit { get; set; } = VolumeUnit.CubicCentimeter;
}

[Serializable]
public class MiscSettings
{
    public bool OutputDebugging { get; set; } = false;
}
```

When I do:

```
Options.Units = OptionsData.Units;
Options.MiscSettings.OutputDebugging = false;
```

The first line executes ok. The second gives me a NullReference Exception. The property Options.MiscSettings is null. The next error is Object not set to an instance of an object.

I've tried renaming everything, changing order of the properties. I also tried moving the property OutputDebugging to the Units class and that worked just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because `Options.MiscSettings` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: You have to create an instance of the object before you use it `public static MiscSettings MiscSettings = new MiscSettings();`

Answer (score 0):

Just because a field is static doesn't mean you don't have to initialize it. Here, `MiscSettings` is never initialized, so it's `null`, and when you try to set its `OutputDebugging` you get the aforementioned `NullReferenceException`.

One easy way to to set `OutputDebuggin` would be to initialize `MiscSettings` with an object initializer:

```cs
Options.MiscSettings = new MiscSettings
{
    OutputDebugging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(Options.MiscSettings==null) Options.MiscSettings=new MiscSettings();
Options.MiscSettings.OutputDebugging = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a class object, you need to make sure to initialize the variables you will use. The MiscSettings variable is not set, therefore you are getting a NullReferenceException.`Options.MiscSettings = new MiscSettings();`